# PHP base URL in external js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have few JS in HTML page, if I use this in HTML view file then its working fine, my page submit form correctly without any issue.

But when I moved this JS codes to external JS file, then it shows error,

Below is my JS

```
$("#user_fm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/peoples/add_user",
            data: $("#user_fm").serialize(),
-----
```

my problem is clear to me, that in view page this is easily get decoded to my url

```
"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/peoples/add_user"
```

but when i keep this in JS file it show like below in console,

```
POST http://localhost/center/index.php/admin/peoples/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();%20?%3Eindex.php/admin/peoples/add_user
```

How can we put PHP codes in JS file?

Comment: You can't place php code inside a js external file.

Comment: You can make a global base_url variable in javascript and assign it manually.

Comment: you can also write in the view file  like

<input type="hidden" name="baseurl" id="baseurl" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">

in javascript 

baseurl = $('#baseurl').val();

Comment: Note that you can refer to *base url* using a slash `/`. In JS, you can use `location.host` or `location.hostname`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to embed PHP in html or javascript code, like `<?php echo base_url();?>`, the file must have `.php` extension, while your external javascript file certainly has `.js` extension. 
Besides `.js` files are parsed by the browser, while PHP files must be executed on the server.

What you can do is to first define a variable in inline javascript, and then use it in code of external `.js` files. In index.php or whatever main file you use, place this before you use your external js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseURL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

And then in your external code:

```
$("#user_fm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseURL + "index.php/admin/peoples/add_user",
            data: $("#user_fm").serialize(),
-----
```

Comment: For Using This Solution Just Keep in mind that you have to put the Script tag before the external js script.  Thanks @n-dru

Answer (score 1):

clearly you cant access.
Run your script with XXAMP YOU need to turn apache service on  so that php can read YOUR base URL